# Is there a simple way to crossvalidate Flutter Form TextFormFields?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have 3 `TextFormField`s for inputting of telephone numbers on a Flutter `Form` (daytime, evening and mobile).

Validation for each `TextFormField` (in the `validator:`) allows a blank string to be input.

But I don't want the form to be saved unless there is at least **one** phone number entered.

`formKey.currentState.validate` will obviously validate all individual fields as being valid.

So is there a simple way in the framework to cross validate **all** the `TextFormFields` and display an error without having to write individial validators for each `TextFormField` and include references to specific fieldnames (which I regard as being a bit of a dirty hack) e.g.

```
String _validatePhoneNumber(String value) {

    // dirty bit - means I have to write a separate validator for each TextFormField rather than use a generic validator 
    if (value.isEmpty && this.eveningNumber.isEmpty && this.mobileNumber.isEmpty)
        return 'At least one number must be included';

    if (value.isEmpty) return null;

    if (_invalidNumber(value))
        return 'Enter a valid phone number';

    return null;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `TextEditingController` to each `TextFormField`, that way you can check the value of each field when you submit your form.

For example:

```
class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  _MyFormState createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {

final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
TextEditingController first = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController second = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     body: Center(
       child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
             children: <Widget> [
               TextFormField(
                 controller: firstController
                 // rest of your stuff
               )
               // rest of your text fields using subsequent controllers
               // secondController, thirdControler... 
             ]
           )
         )
       )
   }
}
```

Then whenever you want to check it's value you just call `firstController.text` or better if you want to know if it's empty you just call `firstController.text.isEmpty`

Comment: Thanks. Just like you to know I do appreciate you taking the trouble to submit an answer :-)